# url.appendPathComponent yields an errorCannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns

Tags: swift, url

in Swift, why does this code yields an error :

`URL(string:"string a”)!.appendPathComponent(“string b”)`

error : `'Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns'`

while this code works :

`var url: URL=URL(string: "string a")!
url.appendPathComponent(“string b")`

Comment: an issue I just had was I was using `appendPathComponent ` instead of  `appendingPathComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse this happens. because you are trying to change the value which is immutable and it is impossible.

you can see that URL() is struct(value) type, and it's initializer `URL(string: )` returns you immutable copy.

you said that this below code is working.

```
var url: URL=URL(string: "string a")!
url.appendPathComponent(“string b")
```

Because, your are creating the mutable copy of that URL struct in `url` variable. and also you can see that `appendPathComponent` is mutating function. so you can apply modification on that mutable copy.